# Transform a dictionary in a list in Python

Tags: python, django

I would like get data from id property and transform in a list

```
queryset = [{"id":1,"name":"John"},{"id":2,"name":"John"}]
```

Expected result

```
('1','2')  ## ID PROPERTY
```

Comment: Do you really want to change the numbers to strings? And the result to be a tuple, not a list?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Some sample code might help us understand your problem better.

Comment: Sorry thats a list what I need, not a tuple, my expected result is [1,2] in integer or string whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tuple(str(query['id']) for query in queryset)
```

Comment: Thank you, I only changed to list() and worked well.

Answer (score 2):

Map each value in `queryset` and convert to tuple:

```
tuple(map(lambda x: str(x['id']), queryset))
```

Comment: @RajaSimon Huh? *Yours* is better (except possibly for the list vs generator issue).

Answer (score 1):

To match what you actually asked:

```
[d["id"] for d in queryset]
```

To get your expected result (that doesn't match your question because the IDs are converted into string and the final result is actually a tuple, not a list):

```
tuple(str(d["id"]) for d in queryset)
```

But since it's probably Django related, the best solution is the one from Iain Shelvington ([see doc here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)):

```
queryset.values_list('id', flat=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the dictionary and add each value with key "id" to a new list:

```
queryset = [{"id":1,"name":"John"},{"id":2,"name":"John"}]

result = []

for item in queryset:
    result.append(str(item['id']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged with Django I assume that query set is actually a Django `QuerySet` object?

If so then there is a simple solution using the ORM [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
queryset.values_list('id', flat=True)
```

Comment: How is it slower? The original answer generates a list which is then transformed into a tuple. The modification removes the intermediary step of generating a list which is quicker and consume less memory

Comment: Well, list comprehensions tend to be faster than generators. Please provide evidence that yours is quicker. Here's my evidence that yours is slower: https://ideone.com/3oXd3l

Comment: I don't think this is a 'rude' answer. It's a different way of approaching the problem and arguably much more 'django-istic' & readable. IMO it's a valid, and appropriate answer.